# POSIX4 messages queues "mq_open: No such file or directory"

Tags: c, posix, mq

I'm trying to use POSIX4 messages queues. So I'm using `mq_open` to create the queue, and for all the options I give to it an `struct mq_attr`, that I fill.

He can't find the queue, while I put the `O_CREATE` flag.

Here is my code *(no-indented lines are debug code)*:

```
...
/***
 * Queues' names
 */
#define GUI_QUEUE "/guiQ"
...
  struct mq_attr attrAct;       /* Queue parameters */
  /***
   * Message queue to send action
   */
  attrAct.mq_maxmsg=1;
  attrAct.mq_msgsize=sizeof(gui_action);
  attrAct.mq_flags=0;
  attrAct.mq_curmsgs=0;

printf("serveur first sizeof(gui_action) : %lu\tmsgsize : %lu\n", sizeof(gui_action), attrAct.mq_msgsize);
  if ((guiQue=mq_open(GUI_QUEUE, O_CREAT | O_NONBLOCK | O_WRONLY
      , S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR , &attrAct))!=0) {
    perror("mq_open");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
if (mq_getattr(guiQue, &attrAct)!=0) {
perror("mq_getattr");
}
else {
printf("serveur second sizeof(gui_action) : %lu\tmsgsize : %lu\n", sizeof(gui_action), attrAct.mq_msgsize);
}
struct mq_attr new;
new=attrAct;
new.mq_msgsize=sizeof(gui_action);
printf("serveur third sizeof(gui_action) : %lu\tmsgsize : %lu\n", sizeof(gui_action), new.mq_msgsize);
if (mq_setattr(guiQue, &new, &attrAct)!=0) perror("mq_setattr");
if (mq_getattr(guiQue, &attrAct)!=0) {
perror("mq_getattr");
}
else {
printf("serveur fourth sizeof(gui_action) : %lu\tmsgsize : %lu\n", sizeof(gui_action), attrAct.mq_msgsize);
}
...
```

And here is the output:

```
serveur first sizeof(gui_action) : 16   msgsize : 16
mq_open: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You tried to open a queue on the root of the filesystem. The code did not have the permissions to do so.

Comment: Yes, but if I put `"guiQ/"` or `"guiQ"`, There is an invalid argument error. So, how can I open a mq in the user space ? (Even with 'sudo', it's not working)

Comment: Check the directory where the compiled executable code is residing in, do you have `guiQ` in there, if not, you need to provide more debugging info, what was the `errno`? using it in the root, i.e. `/` is not the correct place to have it.

Comment: @t0mm13b If using Linux, you are required to name the queue with a starting '/' according to the mq_overview manpage.

Comment: There is no `guiQ` in my dev directory, but there is one in `/dev/mqueue`, and I'm the owner and there is r/w access. With sudo, I have the same error.

Comment: @Phantom Have you tried removing it then running your program?

Comment: sounds like it attempted to create the queue, but one already existed so it refused and error'd out.

Comment: I deleted the file, and it created again. I add `mq_unlink(GUI_QUEUE);` at the beginning of my program, but the problem is still here.

Comment: please provide a proper error message that is returned, did you even step into it and inspect the value of `errno`? use `strerror(errno)` to give the clue.

Comment: `strerror` give the same that I had with `perror`: `No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`mq_open` returns `(mqd_t) -1` on failure and a message queue descriptor on success.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mq_open.html#tag_16_338_04)

You are mistaking the successful return of `mq_open` (which, in practice, is an integer >= 0) for failure, and `perror` is reporting some previous system call's `errno`.